# throwing exception in read method in ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, exception

When I was reading `ByteArrayInputStream` sources I saw that method `read` does not throw `IOException` despite having `throws` in `read` method declaration of `InputStream` class.

Before I kept method signature the same while overriding method. So if a method had declared `throws` -  I implemented it.

But now I am curious - why method `read` in `ByteArrayInputStream` does not throws `IOException`(such error can never occur?) and why such behavior (I mean without `throws IOException` declaration) is allowed?

Comment: Is this a language lawyer question? `ByteArrayInputStream`'s read method returns `-1` when the stream is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically you can only reduce or eliminate the exception thrown in your overridden methods. It is not allowed to throw a broader exception.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/exceptions.html):

> The throws clause of an overriding method may not specify that this method will result in throwing any checked exception which the overridden method is not permitted, by its throws clause, to throw.

So, if the following is part of the base class:

```
public int read() throws IOException;
```

Then, the following rules apply for the subclasses:

```
public int read(); // OK, not broader (but more narrow)

public int read() throws SubClassOfIOException; // Ok, it is not broader (but more narrow)

public int read() throws Exception; // NOT OK, this is broader since Exception is broader than IOException
```

In the case of `ByteArrayInputStream`, there is no reason to throw an `IOException` since it simply can not happen. No I/O against a resource that can throw `IOException` happens here, when all the bytes are read `-1` is simply returned. Therefore the signature is different.

However, when you use the following:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("text".getBytes());
stream.read(); // Must be caught
```

Here, the referenced object is considered to be an `InputStream`. Therefore the `read`-method still is declared to throw an `IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't throw exception because it was implemented in that way to return -1 value. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. It is enough to read byte by byte of data until reach -1 - that's all.